# Opengraph tags (og:tags) in Django template not scraped by Facebook

Tags: python, django, templates, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've been trying to get opengraph tags work for my django website. I use "www.somewebsite.com" as website url during this question. I used the following static code in the header:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="websitename" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.somewebsite.com/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Some description."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.somewebsite.com/static/image.png" />
```

This did not work, so I've installed django-meta (http://django-meta.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) and implemented the following code at my landing page view, so the meta data is added dynamically on the server:

```
# basic page view
class BasicView(View):
    template_name = 'landing/landing.html'

    # get request
    def get(self, request):
        context = {
            "meta": Meta(
               title="Websitename",
               description='Some description.',
               type='website',
               url='https://www.somewebsite.com/', 
               image='https://www.somewebsite.com/static/image.png',
               use_title_tag=True,
               use_facebook=True,
               use_og=True,
            ),
         }

         return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

With the following template:

```
<head {% meta_namespaces %}>
    {% include 'meta/meta.html' %}
</head>
```

This results in:

```
<head  prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
   <meta name="description" content="Some description.">
   <title>Websitename</title>
   <meta property="og:title" content="Websitename">
   <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.somewebsite.com/">
   <meta property="og:description" content="The easiest way of making digital music.">
   <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.judgemysound.com/static/image.png">
</head>
```

When fetching new scrape information in the facebook debugger tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) it gives the following information (image):

[Meta data scraped from my website with facebook sharing debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMSoa.png)

The strange thing is; The information which are in my og tags are not scraped by facebook. Does anyone know how I can make og:tags work on facebook with a Django app?

Thanks!

Comment: No, the strange thing is that you are ignoring the fat error message with the red triangle icon right on top, which as it says must be fixed first, before you can expect any of this to work - your SSL certificate has issues.